# php-wordpress: cannot seem to append variable to href url

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hyperlink, buddypress

In following several tutorials on this, I am trying to append a php variable to a url within a < a> tags but am running into alot of trouble:

```
<?php
$fb='mike.jones';

if($fb) {
echo '<a href="http://facebook.com/' . $fb . '">Facebook</a>';
}
?>
```

Rather than just echoing "Facebook" and linking to http://facebook.com/mike.jones, it outputs: `mike.jones>Facebook` on the front and `mike.jones` is a hyperlink to `www.facebook.com/<a`. The syntax have been matched to the sample codes exactly. What is happening here?

I'm using php 7.2.15.

edit: here is one of the examples I've tried following:
https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-social-media-links-buddypress-profiles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using WordPress and editing a page/post, php code will not be executed correctly because it is usually trimmed and formatted before being saved to the database. You should probably look into a plug-in that allows for PHP code, like [Insert PHP Code Snippet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/) which will allow you to add shortcode to your pages/posts to execute your PHP.

**edit:**
try using the following in your buddypress.php file instead of what you had shared with me:

```
function wdm_add_social_icons() {
  $user_id = $bp->displayed_user->id; // get BP user id
  $fb_page = xprofile_get_field_data('Facebook Profile', $user_id); // get data for user profile field
  if ($fb_page) {
    echo '<a href="https://facebook.com/' . $fb_page . '">FACEBOOK</a>';
  }
}
add_filter('bp_profile_header_meta', 'wdm_add_social_icons');
```

I would also clear your browser cache just to be safe.

Comment: do you mean in the wordpress dashboard's text editor? I've been editing the underlying php files directly, and for other php code, it has been working well.

Comment: @machump, my apologies. Did not know if you were editing files or pages/posts. So using the code you have posted, you're not achieving the desired output of [Facebook](https://facebook.com/mike.jones), but instead receiving [mike.jones](https://www.facebook.com/<a)>Facebook -- correct?

Comment: that's exactly correct. All the examples online seem to be leading to similar unintended results

Comment: The link to the tutorial you've followed seems to have more code for the custom plugin than what you've provided. 1) What file are you putting this code in? 2) Can you provide the code you have in said file exactly as it is? (omitting any private/sensitive info of course)

Comment: i put the code in a file called `buddypress.php` which is located in my theme directory. Selecting a user's profile will use `buddypress.php` as the template. Here is the piece of the code in the file relevant to this exercise: `<?php $fb_page = "http://www.facebook.com/" . xprofile_get_field_data('Facebook', 1,'comma');
echo '<a href=' .$fb_page .'>FACEBOOK</a>';`. It has gone through several iterations, this is the last failed version.

Comment: updated my answer with some code you can try based off the tutorial and code you shared. let me know how it goes.

Comment: sir, I will try your solution on Tuesday. Thanks for your help and stay tuned!

Comment: Did it work the way you intended? What was the outcome?

Comment: it turns out the value in the buddypress Facebook field was prefixed with `https://facebook/my.name` so it was causing issues. Upon removing it, your solution worked. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

I would echo only $fb, since that is the variable that will be changing. Depending on the requirements, I would echo it to a hidden html element that JavaScript could pick up or  jQuery.